# How to get the value from input without using v-model in Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, html-framework-7

There is such an example.When you click on the "**add note**" button, it checked whether the **input** is empty or not and adds a block with text entered into the **input**.

How to make the same example without using v-bind because it does not work in framework7?

Tried to do something like that but it doesn't work.

```
et getCat = document.getElementByClassName('inputCat').value;
let newCat = this.getCat;
this.cats.push(this.newCat);
this.newCat = '';
this.saveCats();
```

**A working example with v-model**

```
  <f7-block v-for="(cat, n) in cats">
      <span class="cat">{{ cat }}</span>
      <f7-button fill color="red" @click="removeCat(n)">Удалить</f7-button>
  </f7-block>

    <f7-list form>
        <f7-list-input
          class="inputCat"
          v-model="newCat"
          type="text"
          placeholder="Заметка"
        ></f7-list-input>
        <f7-button fill color="blue" @click="addCat">Добавить заметку</f7-button>
    </f7-list>

export default {
data() {
    return{
        cats:[],
        newCat: null
  }
},
mounted() {
  if (localStorage.getItem('cats')) {
    try {
      this.cats = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cats'));
    } catch(e) {
      localStorage.removeItem('cats');
    }
  }
},
methods: {
  addCat() {
    // убедиться, что было что-либо введено
    if (!this.newCat) {
      return;
    }
    this.cats.push(this.newCat);
    this.newCat = '';
    this.saveCats();
  },
  removeCat(x) {
    this.cats.splice(x, 1);
    this.saveCats();
  },
  saveCats() {
    const parsed = JSON.stringify(this.cats);
    localStorage.setItem('cats', parsed);
  }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Framework7 documentation](https://framework7.io/vue/inputs.html) the @input event is used.

```js
export default {
  data() {
    newCat: null;
  }
}
```

```html
   <template>
    <f7-list form>
        <f7-list-input
          class="inputCat"
          :value="newCat"
          @input="newCat = $event.target.value"
          type="text"
          placeholder="Заметка"
        ></f7-list-input>
        <f7-button fill color="blue" @click="addCat">Добавить заметку</f7-button>
    </f7-list>
    </template>
```

Comment: Please tell me how to transfer this expression **newCat = $event.target.value** from **input** to the code itself, leaving only **newCat** in the input. Like this **@input="newCat"**

Comment: `@input` is a javascript expression. Its basically a shortcut for `input.onChange()` so its setting the data object `newCat` to the value of the input. You access the variable`newCat` that is being reset everytime the input changes. The combo of `:value and @input` replaces `v-model` in Framework7